# VBA Validation xlValidateList for item is string concat of value from 2 columns in row

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have the following code to identify a valid list of values for a particular range in Sheet2 by specifying a range in Sheet1.  Note Sheet 1 is sort've like a database of things and Sheet2 is sort've like a form.

```
Set subRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A14")
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D6:D517").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="='Sheet1'!" & subRange.Address
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Next I would like to update my Validation such that the same range in Sheet2 is confined to a list where each entry is a string concat of two columns in same row of Sheet1. Let a given row in Sheet1 be "r", I would like the item in the validation list to be

```
' a concat of columns A and D infer the list entry
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r,1).Value & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r,4).Value
```

I plan to use arrays to build up this confined list with a for loop over the rows in Sheet1 but I was wondering if there was a better way to setup this Validation restriction. This seems like this is a fairly common action.

Comment: How about concatenating the content of the 2 columns, using a formula, and referring to the range covering those formulas?

Comment: I came up with this `Formula1:="=Sheet1!A1&Sheet1!B1"` based on your suggestion but realized it doesn't yield a range but a value. Can a formula be constructed to yield a range of values based on calculation?  I am wondering if building an array (or some intermediate data structure) is the only way.

Comment: Compute the values on the worksheet, then refer to those computed values. Example: A1 and A2 contain "Hello" and B1 and B2 contain "World". Put formula `=A1&" "&B1` into C1 and pull it down to C2. Finally, make subRange point to C1:C2.

Comment: That would def do the trick and in my case it would suffice because as I mentioned Sheet1 is not really for the user to understand.  Thank you @Excelosaurus for being a sound board. I can definately implement that for now. I would still be interested if there is an elegant solution without this.